# Ignore BST with php strtotime() function

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Is there a way for me to tell the strtotime() function not to change the time I give it into BST? i.e. if do

```
date('g.ia', strtotime("2014-06-25T19:30"))
```

I want to get 7:30pm, just as if I entered

```
date('g.ia', strtotime("2014-06-25T19:30"))
```

(The first one currently returns 6:30pm)

I'm aware I could just write a manual check for the day/month and add an hour if necessary, or just parse the time myself from the string, but both solutions sound a bit messy (I'll have to do this in quite a few places).

Sorry if there's something obvious I'm missing, pretty new to php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `date()` will format time based on your timezone setting. Said that, your example doesn't make sense since `strtotime()` will use current timezone setting to convert input to unix timestamp, and then function `date()` will use again that timezone setting to format timestamp back. You must be changing timezone setting between `strtotime()` and `date()` function calls, like [this demo](https://eval.in/95856).

You can simply use DateTime extension, where you implicitly tell in what timezone is your time:

```php
$dt = new DateTime('2014-06-25T19:30', new DateTimezone('Europe/London'));
echo $dt->format('g.ia');
```